# Protobuf data model usage

Tags: ios, protocol-buffers

I plan to use protobuf for server-client data models. On client side, we have some data models which are not used in server side. For those data classes, is it better to use the protobuf to generate the data models or writing data model classes manually as we usually do?
Any pros and cons for the options we can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really entirely up to you. Depending on the use case, it may or may not make sense. Things to ask yourself are:

- Do you think it's possible that someday this "client-only" data may no longer be client-only? It'll be much easier to start sending it to the server if it's a protobuf from the start.
- Do you think these data model classes could benefit from having methods other than basic getters and setters? You can't add custom methods to protobuf objects.
- If the objects only need getters and setters, consider that using Protobuf often involves a lot less boilerplate code than writing a class by hand, since you only have to define the fields, not the getters/setters for each one. Less noise makes them both quicker to write and easier to read. Sometimes people use Protobufs for data model classes for this reason alone.

Comment: Thanks, Kenton. make sense.